# How to stop spark started from spark-shell

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-spark

I was just playing around with spark using spark-shell. 
I've built the spark with hive in my EC2 instance. Due to network issue, I got disconnected from EC2 instance.

Now when I reconnected and started spark-shell and when I try to create hiveContext I am getting the following error

```
Caused by: ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database /home/ubuntu/work/software/spark/spark-1.2.2/metastore_db.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.privGetJBMSLockOnDB(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.getJBMSLockOnDB(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.boot(Unknown Source)
```

This is because previous spark-shell still running and getting hold of derby DB.

Is there a way to find the pid to kill it?

From [here](http://./bin/spark-class%20org.apache.spark.deploy.Client%20kill%20%3CdriverId%3E), I found `./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.Client kill <driverId>` will kill the spark. But how can I find the driverId?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to connect to the web UI at http://:8088 and then see the active drivers from there?

Comment: Do you mean Spark UI? I see only Active Jobs from Spark UI not active drivers. Please note that I am using Spark 1.2.2